# Identifying exact arraylist causing error in Java

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am working with a relatively large program, and I recently came across the following error:[image]

I understand what the error means, however, how do I identify what array is causing the issue? Using the info in the error statement, I know the array is in the method bprop() and occurs during a set() method call to an array (there are multiple in bprop(). Can I use the 3 digit numbers to somehow identify the exact source of error? Thank you.

Comment: What three digit numbers? The error is in NNetwork.java at lne 86..

Comment: The digit after the colon is the line number of that file.  Please review your source code to find the problem.

Comment: Ok thank you! so 86 is the error line, then what do 444 and 653 represent? @tanjir

Comment: Looks like NNetwork.bprop is trying to set the 1st element (i.e. index 0) of a zero sized ArrayList (i.e. it has no space to hold *ANY* elements). One possible next step: why does the ArrayList have size zero? Is that right?

Comment: 653 and 444 are the line numbers from the Java ArrayList class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 digit numbers (and, in a couple of spots, the 2 digit numbers) represent the line number of the code causing the error.

So, in file CreateNetwork.java, line 17, there is a call to NNetwork.bprop
In line 86 of NNetwork.java, there is a call to java.util.ArrayList.set

Assuming the java.util code is working properly, your error stems from one of these two places.